# Acumatica-sales order default customer

Tags: acumatica

Am trying to set a default customer for CS but am am getting an error "RevisionID' cannot be empty" please assist

```
protected void SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldUpdating(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatingEventArgs e)
{
  SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;

  if(row == null) return;

   if (row.OrderType == "CS" || row.OrderType == "SS")
       {
           row.CustomerID = 7211;  

        } 

   else
       {
           row.CustomerID = null;  
        } 

}
```

Comment: I think you need to have this code in OrderType_FieldUpdated to then trigger the default for the Customer? right now if you are trying to change the value of customerid when the customerid field is updated which will only occur if someone is entering a customer.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case **FieldDefaulting** event must be used instead of **FieldUpdating** to generate default value for the Customer ID field. According to [the API Reference](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=6db70fe7-3fc3-4e05-d3a6-5ecb93bea6a9), in **FieldDefaulting**  event handlers the new value must be assigned to the **NewValue** property of **PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs** and never directly to the DAC field:

```
protected void SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldDefaulting(PXCache cache, PXFieldDefaultingEventArgs e)
{
    SOOrder row = (SOOrder)e.Row;
    if(row == null) return;

    if (row.OrderType == "CS" || row.OrderType == "SS")
    {
        e.NewValue = 7211;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Just make sure the customerid field defaulting will re-run on change of OrderType

Comment: Because OrderType is a key field, every time its value gets updated, the framework will try to find a record with specified OrderType and OrderNbr in the database. If no record was found, a new Sales Order record will be created. This will result in automatic invocation of the FieldDefaulting event for CustomerID on the new Sales Order.

Comment: Thanks RuslanDev,  i have used your code but still getting the same error when trying to save

Comment: on sales order screen

Comment: @jay, any chance the problem can be caused by some other code in your SOOrderEntry BLC extension? Will the error persist if you comment out everything in your SOOrderEntry BLC extension, except the `SOOrder_CustomerID_FieldDefaulting` handler, restart IIS and attempt to create and save a new Sales Order?